# Meteor if helper - how to access this data in each loop

Tags: if-statement, meteor, this, helper, datacontext

I want to give users a button to add the id of a document from one collection (along with their group name) into another collection.

I have an #each loop that returns each document from the first collection via a template helper query.  Within each returned document, I need to check if the id has been added to the other collection, and depending on the outcome, an #if helper in the html returns a different output.

But "this" is returning an empty object, and I don't know how to pass each "this" data context into the "inCollectionTwo" helper:

```
<template name="Collections">
  {{#each doc in colOne}}   
    {{#if inCollection2}}
      {{> rmvfrmcolTwo doc=doc}}
    {{else}}
      {{> addtocolTwo doc=doc}}
    {{/if}}
  {{/each}
</template>
```

**Helpers**

```
Template.Collections.helpers({
  colOne: function() {
    return CollectionOne.find();
  },

  inCollectionTwo: function(){
    var docid = this.colOne._id;
    var group = Meteor.user().profile.groupName;
    var exists = CollectionTwo.findOne({documentid: docid, groups: { "$in": [group]}});
    if(exists) {
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using `each..in`, you are changing the entire data context of that block to the document for each iteration. That document can now be referenced with the `this` keyword within event handlers and helpers.

```
{{#each doc in colOne}}
  {{#if inCollectionTwo)}}
    {{> rmvfrmcolTwo doc=doc}}
  {{else}}
    {{> addtocolTwo doc=doc}}
  {{/if}}
{{/each}}
```

And in your helper:

```
Template.Collections.helpers({
  //...
  inCollectionTwo: function() {
    // `this` is the `doc` from the #each block in your template
    var docid = this._id;

    //...
  }
}
```

**Edit:** Or, you could pass in the new context to the helper as a parameter

```
{{#each doc in colOne}}
  {{#if (inCollectionTwo doc)}}
  ...
```

And in your helper

```
inCollectionTwo: function( doc ) {
  var docid = doc._id;
  //...
}
```

The Meteor Guide has a [detailed section here](http://guide.meteor.com/blaze.html#spacebars) about Blaze and the `each..in` loop. There's a few other ways you could reason about your problem but that should get you started.

Comment: thanks for the input @chazsolo, on the first note, that was just a transposition typo on my part.  I renamed the template, helpers and collections for ease of reading here.  But on your second point, "this" alone is still returning an empty object.  I did try that prior to posting and should have mentioned.

Comment: @edoras you could also try passing in the `doc` to the helper as a parameter, and then accessing it there. Like: `{{#if (inCollectionTwo doc)}}` - I've updated my answer to reflect this